# How to Convert 2 Image to 1 Page PDF With terminal?

Tags: 20.04, pdf, image-processing, convert, imagemagick

I have a question, I have a problem, I want to change 2 images in 1 page pdf, how do I do it? I tried this command

```
convert *.jpg -resize 1240x1753 \
                      -extent 1240x1753 -gravity center \
                      -units PixelsPerInch -density 150x150 multipage.pdf
```

I get the result that 1 image for 1 page only, how to make 2 images 1 page ? so for example I have 10 images, then the result is 5 pages because 1 page 2 images

Comment: Have a look at **Libre Office Draw**. It will let you edit PDF's and it comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like you want to get result without reading documentation. Read it https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php first.

Comment: @N0rbert please how to edit my command ?